# How to import a class in pynecone?

Tags: python, pynecone

I'm trying to import a class in another python class in my pynecone project. It's giving me error.

```
import Constants ---> Giving error
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Constants'

Edit: Folder structure:

[image]

From helloworld.py, I'm trying to import Constants.
How can this be done?

Comment: Does your import point to where the module is? It's hard to say what the problem is without the folder structure.

Comment: Where is `Constants` defined? What is your project structure? Generally, it's `from module_name import ClassName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it's being [imported within the library](https://github.com/pynecone-io/pynecone/blob/main/pynecone/app.py) is

```
from pynecone import constants
```

Comment: This doesn't work. 
He has a folder that its name is "helloworld". If he wants to import Constants file in hellowold file, he has to import as ```from helloworld import Constants```. Or he has to use the __init__.py file

Answer (score 3):

You can simple write:

`from helloworld import Constants`

Other options is use the `__init__.py` file to initialize the modules. You can write `from helloworld import Constants as const` (as is optional) and then, in the `helloworld.py` file write at the top `from helloworld import const` or relative import  `from . import const`